# I cant drag sprites into the animation window in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want to create an animation, but when I drag my sprites(Flat images) in the animation window, it doesn't allow me to drop them.
So, I can't make an animation, which is needed to make a game.
I am a noob, so forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little too vague, but what you will need to do to animate a sprite, you will need to first add it in your scene and then you will be able to animate them. If you're using sprite sheets however [This official tutorial should help](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-sprite-animations#5fa66921edbc2a0020bcaae1)

Comment: Thanks, i didnt select the object in the scene.

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have clicked on the game object that you want to create an animation yet.

Comment: this was it for me.  I had to click on the object then the animation in the animator then the animation panel was able to be dragged upon